# Can we use one SSL certificate on two different hosting

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, xmpp, ssl-certificate

I have server.com domain and SSL certificate bought for same domain. We have two different servers installed on AWS one instance (one IP) one is app server and another is xmpp server. We access xmpp server using port (server.com:port). We were able to use one SSL certificate for both servers. Now as number of hits increased on server we decided to keep xmpp server on different AWS instance. Now we access xmpp server as ip_address:port. We do not need domain to access xmpp server. But certificate used  is no more valid.

I am not a server guy. Is there any way we can handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An SSL certificate is tied to a domain, not a server. Theoretically any number of servers can use the same certificate, but it will only be valid if the server is accessed via the correct domain. You will need to use the domain, not the IP to access both servers.

If it is a wildcard certificate, you could put the server at a subdomain such as `xmpp.server.com`.

You could give [XMPP service records](http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records) a try. I don't know whether the certificate is validated against the domain in the SRV record or against the original domain. I'm guessing it is against the SRV domain, which means this won't help, but maybe it is worth a try.

Otherwise, you need a way for a single IP to continue to handle both services. Have you considered forwarding the XMPP ports from the web server to the XMPP server via firewall rules?

---

Note: RFC 3920 (XMPP Core), Section 5.1 (Use of TLS), Rule #8:

> Certificates MUST be checked against the hostname as provided by the
>   initiating entity (e.g., a user), not the hostname as resolved via the
>   Domain Name System; e.g., if the user specifies a hostname of
>   "example.com" but a DNS SRV[SRV] lookup returned "im.example.com", the
>   certificate MUST be checked as "example.com".

This seems to imply that the SRV record should allow this to work. It seems that [not all clients always follow this spec](https://trac.adium.im/ticket/8787) though.

Comment: Please note that RFC 3920 is obsolete.

Comment: Certificate validated against "original domain"